# Background to cover entire screen

Tags: html, css, background-image, cover

I have a background image which covers my entire scree. However, once I add elements to my html file, the background image only covers the area of this new element, the rest is going to be white.

How can I make sure, that the background continues after my element until the bottom of my screen?

```
#backgroundLanding {
  background: url('/assets/images/landing_new4.jpg'); 
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

<div id="backgroundLanding" >


  <div>
  <!--Flight Search Directive-->
  <!--flight-search>
  </div>


    <!--impressum></impressum-->
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use background-size:cover, it'll show the same. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: do you have any fiddle demo??

Comment: background-size:100% 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not with your background image, you should check the width of your main wrapper and set it to 100% to fit any screen size

Comment: I know what you mean. So the background covers the entire screen. But the html document only sees the part where the the elements are and nothin below. So I'll have no chance to fix anything to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @user3383709 indeed you can. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the position of the wrapper fixed, and add this css:

```
#backgroundLanding {
   position:fixed:
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background-size:cover;
}
```

But this means the content will never scroll. But I believe that is the desired effect.

Plus it will always fill the screen even if new content is added dynamically to the document.

Answer (score 0):

The parent Div's height depends on its child elements if you don't mention explicitly.
That is why you see the background based on the child element.

Mention the necessary height to the parent. If you want it for the whole page, then you can give the background to the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to fill the container, use `background-size: cover;` can achive it and the image still remains its resolution ratio.

However, it looks like your problem is the container is not adapted to the browser window. It will be streched by its child nodes.

@lharby gives one solution. Another solution is like this:

```
html, body {height: 100%;} /* I assume #backgroundLanding is a child node of <body> */
#backgroundLanding {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/landing_new4.jpg'); 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This is also what I used on [**my own blog**](http://myst729.github.io/).